# 404 error- issues with pages after adding custom rules for posts

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, 404-error, multi-language

I am trying to create a custom translation for my website.

**Quick Story:**

I am facing "404 error-Page Not Found' issues with pages after adding custom rules in functions.php

```
$newrules['^th/(.*)$'] = 'index.php?name=$matches[1]';
$newrules['^se/(.*)$'] = 'index.php?name=$matches[1]';
```

with the above code, posts with /th/ slug are working perfectly fine but my pages with /th/page-name-1 ... throwing 404 error-Page Not Found

**So here is the complete story:**

First I created a parent page "Home Thai" https://mywebsite.com/th/
and under that parent page "Home Thai", I added the rest of the Thai language pages, so results coming like this

```
mywebsite.com/th/page-name-1
mywebsite.com/th/page-name-2
mywebsite.com/th/page-name-3
```

Now I want to set up Thai Post URL with slug (/th), and to make this, I added the below new rules in functions.php

```
$newrules['^th/(.*)$'] = 'index.php?name=$matches[1]';
$newrules['^se/(.*)$'] = 'index.php?name=$matches[1]';
```

with the above code, posts are working perfectly with language slug (/th/, /se/). bit my pages with /th/page-name-1 ... throwing 404 error-Page Not Found

**Script:**

```
//Create a function to register a new language translation taxonomy
add_action('init','nk_add_translation_taxonomy');

function nk_add_translation_taxonomy(){
   
    global $post;
    //set the name of the taxonomy
    $taxonomy = 'nk-post-translation';
    //set the types for the taxonomy
    $object_type = array('post');

    //populate our array of names for our taxonomy
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => 'Post Translation',
        'singular_name'      => 'Post Translation',
        'search_items'       => 'Search Translation',
        'all_items'          => 'All Translation',
        'parent_item'        => 'Parent Translation',
        'parent_item_colon'  => 'Parent Translation:',
        'update_item'        => 'Update Translation',
        'edit_item'          => 'Edit Translation',
        'add_new_item'       => 'Add New Translation', 
        'new_item_name'      => 'New Translation',
        'menu_name'          => 'Post Translation',
              
    );
    
    //define arguments to be used 
    $args = array(
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'how_in_nav_menus'  => true,
        'public'            => false,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array('slug' => 'post-translation')
    );
    
    //call the register_taxonomy function
    register_taxonomy($taxonomy, $object_type, $args); 
}

add_filter( 'post_link', 'custom_permalink', 10, 3 ); 
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array','customLangaugeSlugRules');
add_filter( 'init','flushRules'); 

// creating of post permalink from taxnonmy slug
function custom_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
    $category = get_the_terms($post->ID,"nk-post-translation"); 

    if (  !empty($category) && $category[0]->slug == "th" )
    {
      $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url('th/' . $post->post_name ) );
    }
    elseif (  !empty($category) && $category[0]->slug == "se" )
    {
      $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url('se/' . $post->post_name ) );
    }
    else
    {
      $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url( $post->post_name ) ); 
    }
    return $permalink;
}

// using because of its flush the exixsting rules of taxnonmy slug rules
function flushRules(){
  global $wp_rewrite;
  $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

// inserting new rules of taxnonmy slug
function customLangaugeSlugRules($rules)
{
    $newrules = array();

    $newrules['^se/(.*)$'] = 'index.php?name=$matches[1]';
    $newrules['^th/(.*)$'] = 'index.php?name=$matches[1]';

    return $newrules + $rules;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Why it happens

The error 404 on the `th/<page slug>` pages occurs because your custom rewrite rules overwrite the default Page rules which would otherwise load the correct Page (having the slug `<page slug>`).

### How to fix the issue

If your permalink structure is `/%postname%`, i.e. `example.com/<post slug>`, then a simple fix to the error 404 is by using the [`post_rewrite_rules`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_rewrite_rules/) hook instead of `rewrite_rules_array`.

So all you need to do is:

```php
// Change this:
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array','customLangaugeSlugRules');

// to this one:
add_filter( 'post_rewrite_rules','customLangaugeSlugRules');
```

Then flush the rewrite rules — but as the [`WP_Rewrite::flush_rules()` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rewrite/flush_rules/) says: (*slightly reformatted)

> Because this function can be *extremely costly* in terms of
> performance, it should be *used as sparingly as possible – such as
> during activation or deactivation of plugins or themes*. Every attempt
> should be made to avoid using it in hooks that execute on each page
> load, such as
> [`init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/).

So keep that in mind, and you could actually flush the rules manually by simply going to the Permalink Settings admin page (`wp-admin` → Settings → Permalink).